# JavaScript clean up of (local) objects referenced in "delayed" functions

Tags: javascript

Does JavaScript (pure, not jQuery, if it matters) know to clear up/free/release from the last reference to an object in a "delayed" function called from a timer or event?

Take the following code:

```
function myInitFunc()
{
  var myInitObj = new Object();
  myInitObj.properties = lotsOfStuff;

  var myDelayedInitFunc = function ()
  {
    doSomethingWith(myInitObj);
    // I shall not be accessing myInitObj again now.
  };

  // Let's say, *one* of the following:
  setTimeout(myDelayedInitFunc, 1000);
  window.addEventListener('load', myDelayedInitFunc);
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myDelayedInitFunc);
}
```

Note that `myDelayedInitFunc()` is deliberately accessing variable `myInitObj`, which is local to `myInitFunc()`.

In, say, http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks it states "Functions used in setTimeout/setInterval are also referenced internally and tracked until complete, then cleaned up".  Does this "clean up" understand that it can get rid of the `myInitObj` as well as the function itself?  I'm sort of guessing it does....

What about the two event examples?  Even though we know they are "one-shot" events, I'm guessing that neither `myDelayedInitFunc` nor `myInitObj` will get cleaned up?

If it is the case that some of these do *not* clean up, should I make `myDelayedFunc()` set `myInitObj = null;` at its end so as to minimise the wastage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no need for you to clean up that reference. If you're worried that your JS code might have memory leaks, you should perhaps read up on [memory profiling](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling).

Comment: I appreciate your quick response.  Does the "no need to clean up" truly apply to those *events* as well as `setTimeout`?  I can understand the latter, but for the events to clean up that means JavaScript understands those two event names are only ever called once??  I like to understand the *theory*, if possible.

Comment: The theory varies based on which browser you view it from, as each browser has a different garbage collector implementation. If you wish to know more about garbage collection [read this](http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection)...

Comment: Interesting reading in itself, though it did not throw any light on the situations I was asking about. However I shall accept your assertion that this is not something I should worry about, and mark your answer as the solution.